# My deep learning model works with Stratified K-Fold, but not in predicting future time events

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, modeling

I have a project at work where I'm supposed to predict a specific location given cell phone signal parameters.  I developed a deep learning model that uses convolutional neural network on time-ordered parameters of the data.

I initially performed a stratified K-folds testing of the data, to which I got 86% accuracy.  I was then asked to do testing where I tested on all data except for the past 2 days, then test on the recent 2 days of data.  My accuracy has now plummeted to 2%.  Would anyone know why this is?  My guess is there are some imbalance of bins that were not present in the stratified K-folds.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, do you mean you *trained* on all data except for the *last* 2 days (and the tested on the last two)?

This is quite a common problem with time series data. Imagine the following, you're trying to predict a continuous target variable based on some other continuous variable that fluctuates a lot, and you know is not in any way correlated to the target.

If you train a model that massively overfits, for the sake of argument, a decision tree with no minimum leaf size, it will effectively "memorise" that, for example, "when 0.3587

Now, if both the feature and target vary sufficiently slowly in time, then, when doing k-fold cross-validation (randomly I assume rather than stratified), any one of your test examples probably has a few corresponding examples in the training set which were taken very close in time to this one. Thus both the feature and target value are likely to be close to an example in the training data, which the classifier has "memorised".

If however, your test example is sufficiently far in time from any training examples, then your classifier will associate it with the training example whose feature value is closest to your current feature value, and return whatever the target was at that time...which we know is a random guess, if the feature carries no information about the target.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was what I meant.  Trained on everything except the recent two days and trained on it.

That sounds insightful.  I'll investigate my timeframe and see what I get.  Maybe I can narrow down my test data to refer to only timeframes that are close to each other.

Comment: What I should have added, is that the cross-validation you did, which gets you low accuracy, is the correct one, and shows that you're overfitting (perhaps training for too long?)